# Accessing Credentials on TAM Backend Server

Tags: websphere, reverse-proxy, host, tivoli, webseal

I have a setup with Tivoli Access Manager (TAM) as reverse proxy for some application servers on the backend side. TAM is responsible for authenticating users. Is it possible to access the credentials a user passed in during TAM authentication in the backend applications?

I need this because the backend applications connect to a Host-System and there the credentials are needed to log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a couple of options you might have for this :

- Since you mention TAM, I guess you are still using 6.X, so you can use a custom CDAS (Cross-domain Authentication Service) library. You would need to implement the library yourself in C and handle the authentication part and return the clear text password as an extended entitlement in the credential. This will allow you to add this extended entitlement as an injected HTTP header for the junctions that require the password. You can get more information here : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPREK_6.1.0/com.ibm.itame.doc_6.1/am61_web_devref58.htm%23chap-wsd-write-custom
- You can implement your own External Authentication Interface. EAIs are external web applications where WebSEAL can delegate the authentication part. In that EAI, as in CDAS, you would have to handle the authentication part yourself - probably against TAM user registry - and then return the clear text password as an extended attribute in the credential to be used as a custom HTTP header for the junction that requires it.  See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPREK_6.1.0/com.ibm.itame.doc_6.1/am61_web_devref128.htm%23appx-wsd-eai
- Leverage Tivoli Federated Identity Manager and a custom STS chain to do the authentication and return the clear text password as part of the credential.

For all 3 of the above options, you would need to modify the existing backend application to read the injected HTTP header and use the clear text password to perform the actions to the Host. 
I have done all 3 for various integrations and I think your best choice is writing an EAI, as CDAS got deprecated with ISAM 7 and the 3rd option requires an additional software component.